# GLSL and OpenGL2 is required for the LWJGL renderer

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, jmonkeyengine, video-card

I have a problem with my first JMonkeyEngine program. I am getting this:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GLSL and OpenGL2 is required for the LWJGL renderer!
    at com.jme3.renderer.lwjgl.LwjglRenderer.initialize(LwjglRenderer.java:165)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext.initContextFirstTime(LwjglContext.java:231)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext.internalCreate(LwjglContext.java:271)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:117)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know this is because I need GLSL and OpenGL2 (found [here](http://jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/where-can-i-get-glsl-and-opengl2/)) but I seem to already have the latest graphics card driver:

[image: The best driver software for your device is already installed]

How can I fix this? (note: I am following the tutorial [here](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_simpleapplication))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Third_generation)
>
> How can I fix this?

Install a newer OpenGL implementation.

[Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/) has a free one.  Might be kinda slow though.

Comment: Easiest way would be to get a newer video card and associated drivers.  The Mesa software rasterizer will work, albeit slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Windows supports OpenGL 1.4 or something similar.
You should download drivers from vendors website.
e.g. NVidia website

Comment: Does this mean I need a new graphics card?

Comment: First download driver from card vendor not from Microsoft. Microsoft does not support latest versions of OpenGL

Comment: + you do not say what video adapter you have.